# Python BeautifulSoup : Is there a way to count the number of results crawled?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to count the number of results crawled in BeautifulSoup?

Here is the code.

```
def crawl_first_url(max_page):
    page = 1

    while page <= max_page:
        url = 'http://www.hdwallpapers.in/page/' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')

        for div in soup.select('.thumb a'):
            href = 'http://www.hdwallpapers.in' + div.get('href')
            crawl_second_url(href)
        page += 1

def crawl_second_url(second_href):
    #need to count the number of results here.
    #I tried, len(second_href) but it doesn't work well.

crawl_first_url(1)
```

I want the second function to count the number of crawled results, for exemple if 19 urls have been crawled I want it the amount.

Comment: What does `crawl_second_url` do?  Does it only count results?

Comment: @dstudeba Yeah it should only count the number of result, but I don't know how I can do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want to count the number of results, I don't see a reason to have a separate function, just add a counter.

```
page = 1
numResults = 0

while page <= max_page:
    url = 'http://www.hdwallpapers.in/page/' + str(page)
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')

    for div in soup.select('.thumb a'):
        href = 'http://www.hdwallpapers.in' + div.get('href')
        numResults += 1
    page += 1

print("There are " + numResults + " results.")
```

This will only count the number of subpages.  If you also want to count the top level pages just add another increment line after the soup.  You might also want to add a `try: except:` block to avoid crashes.